# Where do I put my WAR file on my Pivotal TC server?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war, pivotal-web-services

I'm trying to teach myself how to use Java with Pivotal TC server. I have a Cloud9 account where I set up a server with Pivotal TC. I also created a simple Hello World app in Spring Tool Suite and exported it on my desktop as a WAR file.

So I have this WAR file, and I have this server on Cloud9. I've googled where to put it, and I've gotten different results, and none of them have related to my set up.

I have the directory in my server as `/opt/pivotal/pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.1.3.SR1/tomcat-8.0.30.C.RELEASE`, and inside of that I have a bin and lib folder. Where exactly do I put my WAR file so that my app is correctly placed in my server?

Am I over-simplifying this? Are there other steps that I just skipped? Or do I just need to play the WAR file somewhere? This was my understanding. I'm pretty new to Java so bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create instance (like domain) for hosting your app

```
# lets alias tc-server location to shorten commands
$TC_SERVER=/opt/pivotal/pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.1.3.SR1
$TC_SERVER/tcruntime-instance.sh create myserver
```

After that new director myserver will appear inside $TC_SERVER (like /opt/pivotal/pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.1.3.SR1/myserver)

Put your war inside $TC_SERVER/myserver/webapps
To start the app

```
cd $TC_SERVER/myserver/bin
./tcruntime-ctl.sh start
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm running into a problem. When I run the first couple lines, I get the error `The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined`. I've tried to set this in /etc/environment and /etc/profile, but it still gives me this error.

Comment: Forget it. I got it to work. The directories are a bit different. Thanks for your help!